# User needs accounts merged

Tags: support, moderators

I had rejected some substantial edits done by an "anonymous user" on [Daniel Moskovich's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7751/daniel-moskovich) [answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24735/is-there-a-gap-in-the-standard-treatment-of-simplicial-homology/24848#24848)

I made a comment suggesting that if it was Daniel making the edits, he should log in to make the edits without having to go through approval. He seems [to have re-registered](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7803/daniel-moskovich) instead.

The accounts should be merged.

As long as I'm at it, should bringing this to the moderators' attention be done via a flag on the answer, or through the meta site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flagging is the simplest way to deal with it. If there are substantial explanations that cannot fit in the textfield, I encourage you to e-mail the moderators. Robin's, Akhil's, Qiaochu's, and my e-mail addresses are all publicly available on our user profiles.